# Converting Json to CSV with Custom Mappings in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a JSON File to CSV using Pandas. But the criteria is that there are specific transformations that need to be done for specific fields in the JSON file and then it can be put in the CSV file.

I am using the below code for the same

```
def process_file():
datamapping={
    "Document Line Number":"InvoiceLineNumber",
    "Line Distribution Number":"SplitAccountingNumber|check0",
    "Line Description":"Description",
    "Posting Date":"AccountingDate.Day|Date",
    } 
columns=["Document Line Number","Line Distribution Number","Line Description","Posting Date"]
df_csv=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)  // creating the dataframe with columns
    for k in dbutils.fs.ls(files.path):
        file_content=dbutils.fs.head(k.path,20000000)
        data=json.loads(file_content)
        df=pd.json_normalize(data)
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            emplis=[]
            for d in columns:
                k= datamapping.get(d,None)
                if k is not None:
                    k=k.split('|')
                    if len(k)==1:
                        emplis.append(row[k[0]])
                    else:
                        data=k[0]
                        operand=k[1]
                        if operand=='Date':
                            txt=row[data]
                            txt=datetime.datetime.strptime(txt,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
                            emplis.append(datetime.datetime.strftime(txt,'%Y-%m-%d'))
                        elif {{other criterias}}:
                            .........
                            .........
                                    
                else:
                    emplis.append(" ")
            df_csv.loc[len(df_csv.index)]=emplis
df_csv.to_csv(download_folder+'/extract.csv',index=False)
```

In the code `datamapping` contains the mapping of the fields needs to be done from json to csv and `|` is used as a seperator if there is any specific logic that needs to be implemented like `"Posting Date":"AccountingDate.Day|Date` means `AccountingDate.Day` from JSON needs to be added to `Posting Date` column after performing the `date` transformation similarly there are other transformations as well.

The code is currently working as expected and is producing the expected results also, but the code is a bit sluggish.

NB:- AT later point of time there might be few API calls also needs to be integrated for specific fields.

Can anyone suggest a better way of implementing the same logic, and preferably using the same libraries?